# Best Way To Mutate Arrays in Structs?

Tags: arrays, struct, rust, mutable

I have a struct like the following

```
struct Foo {
   x: [i8;64]
   y: i8
}
```

And I want to update a value inside array `x` in `Foo` when I pass it through a function. The best solution I can come up with is make a mutable copy of `x` and then update that copy, and then create a new `Foo` with the new array.

```
fn updateFoo(myFoo: Foo, index: usize, newvalue: i8) -> Foo {
    let mut newX = myFoo.x;
    newX[index] = newvalue;
    Foo {
         x: newX,
         y: myFoo.y,
    }
}
```

**Is this an efficient and idiomatic way of mutating arrays within a struct in Rust?** What alternatives are there for me to update values inside of an array inside Rust? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Rust myself, so aren't qualified to answer - but can't you just have the `myFoo` argument be a mutable reference, rather than be "owned"? Then you can directly mutate by `myFoo.x[index] = newValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also just pass in a mutable ref to Foo:

```rust
struct Foo {
    x: [i8; 64],
    y: i8,
}

fn updateFoo(myFoo: &mut Foo, index: usize, newvalue: i8) {
    myFoo.x[index] = newvalue;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8db910a5e49287d5f16d84d6231afe7c)